# "Тренировка" или "тренеровка"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "тренировка" или "тренеровка"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно "тренироваться". Даже несмотря на то, что "тренер". Это иностранное слово, которое нужно запомнить.

Comment: Несмотря на... пишется слитно в предыдушем ответе, потому что можно заменить "вопреки". ТренИРОВАться, в слове тренер сейчас уже выделяется суффикс -ЕР.


Comment: Я знаю. В данном случае это была опечатка. Спасибо.

Comment: Предыдущий ответ? Не смешите меня.